# not work pipe for search

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

i create pipe for search . when user select complete from selectbox it show complete products and when select the uncomplete show uncomplete product but when i use this code it not show me this Error :

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   The pipe 'SearchCompletePipe' could not be found ("
>   ]task of tasks | SearchCompletePipe:SearchCompletePipe; let index=index" [task]="task">Loading . . .

this my code :

Pipe :

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../task/task-list/task';

@Pipe({
    name: 'search-complete'
})

export class SearchCompletePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(tasks: Task[], args?: any): any {

        if (!tasks) {
            return tasks;
        }

        let complete = args[0];
        return tasks.filter((task: Task) => task.complete == complete)

    }

}
```

task-List :

```
    import { Component, OnInit,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from './task';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-list',
  templateUrl: './task-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-list.component.css']
})
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {

    complete: boolean = false;
    @Output() tasks: Task[];
    constructor() {
        this.tasks = [
            new Task(1, "Site Design", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci autem consequuntur ea exercitationem fuga, illo impedit ipsam itaque magnam mollitia nihil quam quibusdam repellendus, reprehenderit totam vel. Beatae, eum.", false),
            new Task(2, "Site Design", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci autem consequuntur ea exercitationem fuga, illo impedit ipsam itaque magnam mollitia nihil quam quibusdam repellendus, reprehenderit totam vel. Beatae, eum.", false),
            new Task(3, "Site Design", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci autem consequuntur ea exercitationem fuga, illo impedit ipsam itaque magnam mollitia nihil quam quibusdam repellendus, reprehenderit totam vel. Beatae, eum.", false),
            new Task(4, "Site Design", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci autem consequuntur ea exercitationem fuga, illo impedit ipsam itaque magnam mollitia nihil quam quibusdam repellendus, reprehenderit totam vel. Beatae, eum.", false),

        ];
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

task.html:

```
<app-task-item 
               *ngFor="let task of tasks | complete:SearchCompletePipe ; let index=index"
               [task]="task"
               >Loading . . .</app-task-item>
```

task-item :

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../task';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-task-item',
    templateUrl: './task-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./task-item.component.css']
})
export class TaskItemComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() task: Task;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

task.html:

```
<td class="col-lg-1">{{task.id}}</td>
<td class="col-lg-2">{{task.name}}</td>
<td class="col-lg-6">{{task.description}}</td>
<td class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">delete</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">done</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Please re-read the guidance, that usage is not correct: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: @jonrsharpe whats this problem ?

Comment: is your true code?, look the error and search it in your code, the more similiar code is in ```task.html``` but not equal.

Comment: no its not true . i ask the question for find wrong part in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the name of `pipe` that you've declared on your Pipe *decorator*:

In your case, it's `search-complete`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search-complete'
})
```

So, in **template**

```
<app-task-item *ngFor="let task of tasks | search-complete: complete; let i = index"
               [task]="task">
  Loading...
</app-task-item>
```

**Wait!** it doesn't work either. Why?

Because it gives template parse errors.

I really can't tell the reason, but I'm almost sure that Angular doesn't accept special characters (like dash, underscore, etc...) on `name` *metada* of `@Pipe` *decorator*.

**Solution?**

Use *camelCase*. So, instead of `search-complete` you **must** use  something like `searchComplete` (it's more readable also :) )

**Pipe**:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchComplete'
})
```

**Template**

```
<app-task-item *ngFor="let task of tasks | searchComplete: complete; let i = index"
               [task]="task">
  Loading...
</app-task-item>
```

**Additional notes:**

1 - Actually you're treating the parameter of the pipe as an `array` (on your *transform function*), but you're passing a single variable. To make it working you can wrap the *complete* param with *brackets*, like this (and keep the pipe as before):

```
<app-task-item *ngFor="let task of tasks | searchComplete: [complete]; let i = index"
               [task]="task">
  Loading...
</app-task-item>
```

or you can keep the HTML as before and make changes in pipe:

```
export class SearchCompletePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(tasks: Task[], complete: any): any { // Type complete as boolean?  
    if (!tasks) {
      return tasks;
    }

    return tasks.filter((task: Task) => task.complete === complete)    
  }    
}
```

2 - Don't forget to add `SearchCompletePipe` in your declarations array in your `NgModule`.

Answer (score 0):

`The pipe could not be found` error means you have forgotten to introduce it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SearchCompletePipe
  ]
```

Comment: i add this but still show me error : `declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TaskComponent,
        TaskListComponent,
        TaskItemComponent,
        SearchCompletePipe,
        TaskDetailComponent
    ]`